# How to read file excel row and sheet specific using openXML C# into data table

Tags: c#, datatable, openxml

How to read excel row and sheet specific using open XML C# into data table?

Comment: Any efforts so far? What are the hurdles in completing this task?

Comment: I can only read excel file in first sheet and first row, how i read second sheet and row B31? my code same http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Read-and-Import-Excel-data-to-DataTable-using-OpenXml-in-ASPNet-with-C-and-VBNet.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;

        private void readExcel(Stream file)
        {
            String sheetName = "Sheet2";
            String delimiter = ";";
            int startColumn = 2;// 2 convert to B 
            int endColumn = 6; // read until column 6
            int startRow = 31; // start read from row 31

            String columnRequest = "Request";
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.Add(columnRequest);
            DataRow dr;
            String stringRequest = "";
            String stringNopek = "Init";
            String value = "";
            int indexRow = 0;
            using (SpreadsheetDocument myDoc = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(file, false))
            {
                WorkbookPart wbPart = myDoc.WorkbookPart;

                indexRow = startRow;
                while (!stringNopek.Equals(""))
                {
                    stringNopek = getCellValue(GetExcelColumnName(startColumn) + indexRow.ToString(), sheetName, wbPart).Trim();
                    stringRequest = stringNopek;
                    if (!stringNopek.Equals(""))
                    {
                        dr = dt.NewRow();
                        for (int i = startColumn + 1; i <= endColumn; i++)
                        {
                            value = getCellValue(GetExcelColumnName(i) + indexRow.ToString(), sheetName, wbPart).Trim();
                            stringRequest += delimiter + value;
                        }
                        dr[columnRequest] = stringRequest;
                        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
                    }
                    indexRow++;
                }
            }

            Session["DataTableRequest"] = dt;

            string output = "";
            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                output = output + dt.Rows[i][columnRequest].ToString();
                output += (i < dt.Rows.Count) ? Environment.NewLine : string.Empty;
            }

        }

private string GetExcelColumnName(int columnNumber)
        {
            int dividend = columnNumber;
            string columnName = String.Empty;
            int modulo;

            while (dividend > 0)
            {
                modulo = (dividend - 1) % 26;
                columnName = Convert.ToChar(65 + modulo).ToString() + columnName;
                dividend = (int)((dividend - modulo) / 26);
            }

            return columnName;
        }

 private int ColumnIndex(string reference)
        {
            int ci = 0;
            reference = reference.ToUpper();
            for (int ix = 0; ix < reference.Length && reference[ix] >= 'A'; ix++)
                ci = (ci * 26) + ((int)reference[ix] - 64);
            return ci;
        }

private String getCellValue(String cellReference, String sheetName, WorkbookPart wbPart)
        {
            Sheet theSheet = wbPart.Workbook.Descendants<Sheet>().
              Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).FirstOrDefault();
            if (theSheet == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(sheetName);
            }
            WorksheetPart wsPart =
                (WorksheetPart)(wbPart.GetPartById(theSheet.Id));
            Cell theCell = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().
              Where(c => c.CellReference == cellReference).FirstOrDefault();

            String value = "";

            if (theCell != null)
            {
                if (theCell.CellValue != null)
                {
                    value = theCell.CellValue.Text;
                }
                else
                {
                    value = value = theCell.InnerText;
                }
                if (theCell.DataType != null)
                {
                    switch (theCell.DataType.Value)
                    {
                        case CellValues.SharedString:

                            var stringTable =
                                wbPart.GetPartsOfType<SharedStringTablePart>()
                                .FirstOrDefault();
                            if (stringTable != null)
                            {
                                value =
                                    stringTable.SharedStringTable
                                    .ElementAt(int.Parse(value)).InnerText;
                            }
                            break;

                        case CellValues.Boolean:
                            switch (value)
                            {
                                case "0":
                                    value = "FALSE";
                                    break;
                                default:
                                    value = "TRUE";
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }

            return value;
        }

 protected void UploadControl_FileUploadComplete(object sender, FileUploadCompleteEventArgs e){
 Stream strm = e.UploadedFile.FileContent;
readExcel(strm);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK you need to implement two things:

1. Get the desired worksheet object
2. Get the desired cell i.e. B31 to read the data from

Here is code snippet to get the worksheet object by name, and cell object by address:

```
Private Function GetWorksheet(ByRef document As SpreadsheetDocument, ByVal worksheetName As String) As Worksheet
    Dim sheets As IEnumerable(Of Sheet) = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Descendants(Of Sheet)().Where(Function(s) s.Name = worksheetName)
    If (sheets.Count = 0) Then
        ' The specified worksheet does not exist.
        Return Nothing
    End If
    Dim worksheetPart As WorksheetPart = CType(document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(sheets.First.Id), WorksheetPart)

    Return worksheetPart.Worksheet
End Function

Private Function GetCellByAdrress(ByRef ws As Worksheet, addressName As String) As Cell

    Dim sheetData As SheetData = ws.GetFirstChild(Of SheetData)()
    Dim cell As Cell = Nothing

    Dim rowNumber As UInt32 = GetRowIndex(addressName)
    Dim row As Row = GetRow(sheetData, rowNumber)

    ' If the cell you need already exists, return it.
    ' If there is not a cell with the specified column name, insert one.  
    Dim refCell As Cell = row.Elements(Of Cell)().Where(Function(c) c.CellReference.Value = addressName).FirstOrDefault()
    'refCell.Remove()
    If refCell IsNot Nothing Then
        cell = refCell
    Else
        cell = CreateCell(row, addressName)
    End If
    Return cell
End Function

Private Function GetRowIndex(ByVal address As String) As UInt32
    Dim rowPart As String
    Dim l As UInt32
    Dim result As UInt32 = 0

    For i As Integer = 0 To address.Length - 1
        If UInt32.TryParse(address.Substring(i, 1), l) Then
            rowPart = address.Substring(i, address.Length - i)
            If UInt32.TryParse(rowPart, l) Then
                result = l
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Return result
End Function

 Private Function GetRow(ByRef wsData As SheetData, ByVal rowIndex As UInt32) As Row
    Dim row = wsData.Elements(Of Row)().Where(Function(r) r.RowIndex.Value = rowIndex).FirstOrDefault()
    If row Is Nothing Then
        row = New Row()
        row.RowIndex = rowIndex
        wsData.Append(row)
    End If
    Return row
End Function

Private Function CreateCell(row As Row, address As [String]) As Cell
    Dim cellResult As Cell
    Dim refCell As Cell = Nothing

    ' Cells must be in sequential order according to CellReference. 
    ' Determine where to insert the new cell.
    For Each cell As Cell In row.Elements(Of Cell)()
        If String.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, address, True) > 0 Then
            refCell = cell
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    cellResult = New Cell()
    cellResult.CellReference = address

    row.InsertBefore(cellResult, refCell)

    Return cellResult
End Function
```

Code to consume the functions:

```
Function ReadCellValue(address as string, worksheetName as string)    


    dim worksheet = GetWorksheet(docObj, worksheetName)

    dim cellObj as Cell = GetCellByAdrress(worksheet, "B31")
    if cellObj isnot Nothing
    dim value  = cellObj.CellValue
    end if

 End Function
```

Hope this would help. Let me know in case of any ambiguity.

Comment: Can you please use online converter tool for this purpose? For example: http://converter.telerik.com/